# Proving there exists a unique solution close to a point in a non linear system of equations.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the system of non linear equations $$\begin{cases}x^2y^3+x^3y^2+x^5y+1=a \\ xy^2-2x^2y^4+3x^3y=b\end{cases}$$

How can I prove that for a $(a,b)$ close to $(4,2)$ there is a unique solution $x=f(a,b)$, $y=g(a,b)$ close to $(1,1)$?

Note that when $a=4,b=2$ the system has the solution $x=1,y=1$

Comment: Inverse function theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Comment: So if I calculate the Jacobian of the vector-valued function of $\mathbb{R^2}$ defined by $F(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} x^2y^3+x^3y^2+x^5y+1-a \\ xy^2-2x^2y^4+3x^3y-b \end{pmatrix}$ And this Jacobian is non-zero in $x=1,y=1$ that would mean that there is a unique solution $x=f(a,b)$, $y=g(a,b)$ close to $(1,1)$?

Comment: Yes, not only that, but the mappings $f$ and $g$ are infinitely differentiable!